# Excel Chart, Axis Label decimal removal

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a Y axis that looks like so:

[image]

How can I

1. Remove the `.00` decimals?
2. Make the negative values displayed with a red font?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Select the axis, right-click and choose "Format Axis" from teh pop-up menu

[image]

Under "number", Enter `0` (or the number of decimal places you want)

You can also choose to have negatives diaplayed in red there.

[image]